# Отфильтровать массив объектов

Tags: javascript, фильтрация

Всем доброго времени суток!
У меня есть массив объектов:

```
const arrayObj = [{
{    
    object:
    {
        id: "1",
        name: 'obj1',
        checkId: '001',
    }
}, {
    object:
    {
        id: "2",
        name: 'obj2',
        checkId: '002',
    }
}, {
    object:
    {
        id: '3',
        name: 'obj3',
        checkId: '003',
    }
}, {
    object:
    {
        id: "4",
        name: 'obj4',
        checkId: '004',
    }
}]
```

Есть массив строк:

```
const arrayCheckIds = ['003', '001']
```

Должен получиться массив строк вида:

```
let filtered = ['obj3','obj1']
```

Подскажите плиз как это можно реализовать в JS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сначала строки вида `003`, `001` приводим в нормальный вид. Потом фильтруем массив `arrayobj` и проверяем есть ли id текущего элемента в `arrayCheckIds`. Потом проходимся мапом, чтобы получить только свойство `name`.

```js
const arrayObj = [{
    "object": {
      id: "1",
      name: 'obj1',
      checkId: '001',
    }
  },
  {
    "object": {
      id: "2",
      name: 'obj2',
      checkId: '002',
    }
  },
  {
    "object": {
      id: '3',
      name: 'obj3',
      checkId: '003',
    }
  },
  {
    "object": {
      id: "4",
      name: 'obj4',
      checkId: '004',
    }
  }
];

const arrayCheckIds = ['003', '001'].map(e=>''+Number(e));

console.log(arrayObj.filter(e => arrayCheckIds.includes(e.object.id)).map(e => e.object.name));
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!